# Changing from 1080*1920 to 640*960 Resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, photoshop

I'm designing an app for the iPhone using 1080px X 1920px with 401 ppi

The question: I'd like to adjust the resolution to iPhone 4S & iPhone 5 &iPhone 5S and also for the different iPads.

I tried to create a new document using the correct resolutions but it looks nothing like the 6 Plus design.

What is a good way to adjust resolutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common dilemma, and a good question, but possibly too broad!

Designing adaptive user interfaces (something that will work at multiple resolutions on multiple screens) is important, because it allows easy porting from one device to another.

I can't answer to specifically without more information about your situation, however. Here are some resources though:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

http://www.applicoinc.com/blog/create-one-size-fits-app-ios-ios-8s-adaptive-ui/

https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Comment: I thought I was supposed to use Photoshop to scale the design properly. But I guess it should be done using apple's kits (according to your links)

Comment: I'm glad you're figuring it out! :) Make sure to choose an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to adapt it. 
For iPhone 5,5s,6,6+ if you divide width/hight=aproximate 0,55 so you can scale but for iPhone 4 **you have to do different design because it won't fit or use tables and scrollview to fit all your content**

As for the iPad you should also do another design, as you have much space and you can fit more content inside it but between different iPads resolution, you can use same design for all because they have same screen ratio